# Unable to click on visible Search icon - Selenium Python (Geckodriver)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am not able to click on a visible Search button (Selenium - Python, geckodriver). Tried ID, XPATH and CSS, none of the options work.
Below is the message for Xpath
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //img[@id='pageToolbar_search_image']
Anyone faced similar problems?
Script:
Searchicon=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//img[@id='pageToolbar_search_image']")
Searchicon.click()
Code:

Answer (score 0):

There may be several reasons. Most likely you did not wait for the appearance/rendering or use the wrong locator
If you can find an element by xpath using devtools, then time.sleep() may help, use it before trying to find the element
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Thanks. I verified the locator using Inspect Element/ Console, there seem to be no issues there. There is a time.sleep() statement before trying to find the element.